# Homogeneous Markov Chain $(X_{2n})_{n\in\mathbb{N_0}}$

Tags: markov-chains

Let $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N_0}}$ be a homogeneous markov chain with initial distribution $\mu$ and transition matrix $P$.

Is $(X_{2n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}$ a homogeneous markov chain? What are the initial distribution and transition matrix of it?

How can I prove it?

Comment: What do you think?  Have you done an example?

Comment: I already know it is a homogeneous markov chain. Should I firstly prove if the markov property holds? I haven't done an example.

Comment: Do you know what the transition matrix is?

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Comment: If you figure that out, the fact that it's a homogeneous Markov chain is obvious.  If the chain is in state $i$ what is the probability that it is in state $j$ after two steps?

Comment: I don't understand it. Can you explain it more detailed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p_{ij}$ be the probability that the chain will be in state $j$ at time $t+1$ given that it is in state $i$ at time $t$, so that the transition matrix is $$P=(p_{ij})_{n\times n}$$  Then then probability that the chain will be in state $j$ at time $t+2$ given that it is in state $i$ at time $t$ is $$\sum_{k=1}^np_{ik}p_{kj}\tag1$$ by the law of total probability, because the chain must first transition from state $i$ to some state $k$, and then from state $k$ to state $j$.

I'm sure you recognize the expression in $(1)$.  It's just $P^2_{ij}$.  That is, the transition matrix is $P^2$.  Since this depends only on the state, and not the time, $X_{2n}$ is homogeneous.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What is the initial distribution of $(X_{2n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}$?

Comment: The same as the initial distribution of $X_n$  How could it be any different?  It's the distribution of $X_0$ in both cases.

Comment: That means, the initial distribution of $X_{2n}$ is also $\mu$?

Comment: Yes, of course.